# AWS Athena DDL from parquet file with structs as columns

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I generated an Athena DDL using glue crawler to create an AWS Athena table from a Parquet file stored in S3. However, on copying the DDL and using it in a different AWS account I get the following error :

> line 7:25: mismatched input '<'. expecting: ')', ',' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: ...; proxy: null)

Athena DDL

```
CREATE  TABLE x.y(
  "questiontext" string, 
  "dataexporttag" string, 
  "questiontype" string, 
  "selector" string, 
  "subselector" string, 
  "configuration" struct<ChoiceColumnWidth:bigint,MobileFirst:boolean,QuestionDescriptionOption:string,RepeatHeaders:string,TextPosition:string,WhiteSpace:string>, 
  "questiondescription" string, 
  "choices" struct<1:struct<Display:string>,2:struct<Display:string>,3:struct<Display:string>,4:struct<Display:string>,5:struct<Display:string>,6:struct<Display:string>,7:struct<Display:string>,8:struct<Display:string,ExclusiveAnswer:boolean>,9:struct<Display:string>>, 
  "choiceorder" array<bigint>, 
  "validation" struct<Settings:struct<ForceResponse:string,ForceResponseType:string,Type:string>>, 
  "language" array<int>, 
  "nextchoiceid" bigint, 
  "nextanswerid" bigint, 
  "questionid" string, 
  "questiontext_unsafe" string, 
  "variablenaming" struct<1:string,2:string,3:string,4:string,5:string,6:string,7:string,8:string,9:string>, 
  "datavisibility" struct<Hidden:boolean,Private:boolean>, 
  "recodevalues" struct<1:string,2:string,3:string,4:string,5:string,6:string,7:string,8:string,9:string>, 
  "randomization" struct<Advanced:struct<FixedOrder:array<string>,RandomSubSet:array<int>,RandomizeAll:array<string>,TotalRandSubset:bigint,Undisplayed:array<int>>,EvenPresentation:boolean,TotalRandSubset:string,Type:string>, 
  "defaultchoices" boolean, 
  "gradingdata" array<int>, 
  "searchsource" struct<AllowFreeResponse:string>, 
  "displaylogic" struct<0:struct<0:struct<ChoiceLocator:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,QuestionID:string,QuestionIDFromLocator:string,QuestionIsInLoop:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,1:struct<Conjuction:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,2:struct<Conjuction:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,3:struct<Conjuction:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,4:struct<Conjuction:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,5:struct<Conjuction:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,6:struct<Conjuction:string,Description:string,LeftOperand:string,LogicType:string,Operator:string,RightOperand:string,Type:string>,Type:string>,Type:string,inPage:boolean>, 
  "analyzechoices" struct<6:string,8:string>, 
  "answers" struct<1:struct<Display:string>,2:struct<Display:string>,3:struct<Display:string>,4:struct<Display:string>,5:struct<Display:string>,6:struct<Display:string>>, 
  "answerorder" array<bigint>, 
  "choicedataexporttags" boolean)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

I'm able to query the table using the table generated by the crawler and the schema seems correct. Can anyone help me understand why can't I copy the DDL abd using it for the same file in a different AWS account?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with the DDL statement. How was it generated? I recommend using `SHOW CREATE TABLE x` to generate a DDL statement that will work with Athena.

These are some of the problems:

- The first line is missing `EXTERNAL` between `CREATE` and `TABLE`.
- Column names cannot be quoted with double quotes in Athena DDL. This is a bit weird since this is how you quote them in DML, but DDL is parsed by Hive whereas DML is parsed by Presto and they have different syntaxes ¯\*(ツ)*/¯. If you need to quote column names in DDL the correct character is backtick.
- Struct fields cannot start with numbers. Do these structs really have fields with numeric names? Are they in fact arrays?

You're also probably going to have some trouble with the casing of the field names, Athena is case insensitive and this can trip things up in struct fields, but YMMV.

Glue crawlers are notoriously bad at generating correct schemas when things aren't bog standard and basic. I recommend that you set up your tables by hand and use [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html).

You may wonder how Glue managed to create a table when the DDL can't be used to create another table. The reason is that Glue crawlers use the Glue API. They don't generate a DDL statement and run it through Athena. The Glue APIs don't impose the same rules, because they are made to support multiple services besides Athena, like Spark and Hadoop on EMR, and Redshift Spectrum. Just because there is a table in Glue Data Catalog does not mean it will work with Athena, unfortunately.